# Script for Google Apps Script to send me email notification that specified quota of my Gmail account quota is reached

Tags: javascript

I need a script for Google Apps Script that will trigger/send me email notification that a specified quota (in GB or %) of my Gmail account has been reached or exceeded. I need to execute the script just once and want to ensure it will run every 90 days for 5 years.
Since I don't know programming, I'm presenting the above procedure as I can:
`enter code here`i = 0;
i = i + 90 days;
for k = i to 90x4x5 every i;
if sum (of size of Gmail Inbox+Sent belonging to the account of name1.name2@gmail.com) on i > 10 GB;
then send mail to name1.name2@gmail.com with text “your Gmail account exceeded 10 GB”;
end

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should provide us any draft of your code to be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.